# Does javascript map creates memory leak?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I see many developers use .map() method over .forEach().
Doesn't map create an **unallocated memory** since the returned array doesn't get assigned to a reference?

For example:

```
let obj = {}
a.map(item => {
    item.map((el, i) => {
      obj[el] = i
    })
})
```

Comment: I don't see any _good_ developers doing this. `map` shouldn't be abused as a `forEach` because it eats up memory for no reason, invokes the garbage collector and allocator and is non-semantic. Adding insult to injury, this example breaks scoping--the `map` callback really shouldn't be producing side effects or mutating external state. It should _only_ perform some operation on the current element in a pure way and return the new element--that's it. The memory doesn't leak, though, unless JS is broken.

Comment: `map` and `forEach` are two different things - if you're seeing someone using `map` for the purpose of just iterating over an array then they're using it incorrectly.

Comment: It drives me mad when I see `map` abused like this. `map` is for transforming an array into a new one, and should really only be used with pure functions. If you're just executing some side effect for each array element, you should use `forEach`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this is exceedingly bad practice - simply using `map` over `forEach` with no reason is just wrong. `map` should only be used to directly modify an array, not to iterate over it. The garbage collector comes in and removes the unassigned array generate by `map`, and no memory leaks occur. That code is far better expressed as:

```
let obj = {}
a.forEach(item => {
    item.forEach((el, i) => {
      obj[el] = i
    });
});
```

Or even:

```
let obj = a.reduce((a, c) => ({ ...a, ...(c.reduce((A, C, i) => ({ ...A, [C]: i }))) }));
```

Comment: Who does garbage collecting? Is there difference for this garbage collecting in Node.js vs Browser?

Comment: Not terribly sure @user2734550, all I really know is that when the object has no references to either itself or its child objects, it's released from memory. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management).

Comment: Map isn't used to _modify_ an array, rather to _return_ a new one with (possibly) modified members.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Probably it's just to write a shorter name "map" rather than "forEach".

You are correct, if you don't need the returned mapped array it's better to use forEach, it doesn't allocate neither the array itself nor the elements.

Anyway the returned array is grabbed by the garbage collector and no memory leak will happen.